# Bubble-Sort 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I need to build a code that bubble sort 2D array. The trick here is that I cannot use an one dimensional array helper, or move the items to another array.

The sorting need to be on the 2D array.

Now I built my function. But something is going wrong. This is my output

```
1      1      2      6     12     32
 49     44     54     55    100    344
```

is to close to be done, and I cant think how to do it.

```
 public static int [] [] sortMatrix(int[][]matrix){
    for(int x = matrix.length  ; x >0  ; x-- ){
        for(int i = matrix[0].length  ; i > 0 ; i-- ){
            for(int j = 0 ; j < x  ; j++){
                for(int t = 0 ;t < i    ;  t++){
                    if(t < matrix[0].length - 1 && matrix[j][t] > matrix[j][t+1] ){
                        swap(matrix , j , t, t+1);
                    }
                    else if(t == matrix[0].length - 1 && j != matrix.length -1&& matrix[j][t] > matrix[j+1][0] ){
                        swap1(matrix ,j , t , j + 1);
                    }                       
                }
            }               
        }           
    }
```

Comment: An input-expected output pair would be helpful

Comment: The functions `swap` and `swap1` are not the same?

Comment: nope because one swap is into the rows, and the other is between columns

Comment: int [][] matrix = {{49, 54, 32,1, 2,6} , {1,55,44,100,344,12}};

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 public static int [] [] sortMatrix(int[][]matrix){
    // for loop of matrix rows: -
    for(int x = 0  ; x < matrix.length; x++){
        // for loop of matrix columens: -
        for(int i =0; i < matrix[x].length; i++){
            // for loop of comparison and swapping
            for(int t = 0; t < matrix[x].length - i - 1; t++){
                 if(matrix[x][t] > matrix[x][t+1]){
                      // Swapping operation: -
                      int temp = matrix[x][t];
                      matrix[x][t] = matrix[x][t+1];
                      matrix[x][t+1] = temp;
                 }
            }
        }
    }                         
    return matrix;
}
```

instead of

```
 public static int [] [] sortMatrix(int[][]matrix){
    for(int x = matrix.length  ; x >0  ; x-- ){
        for(int i = matrix[0].length  ; i > 0 ; i-- ){
            for(int j = 0 ; j < x  ; j++){
                for(int t = 0 ;t < i    ;  t++){
                    if(t < matrix[0].length - 1 && matrix[j][t] > matrix[j][t+1] ){
                        swap(matrix , j , t, t+1);
                    }
                    else if(t == matrix[0].length - 1 && j != matrix.length -1&& matrix[j][t] > matrix[j+1][0] ){
                        swap1(matrix ,j , t , j + 1);
                    }                       
                }
            }               
        }           
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for sorting 2D array, trick is that you have to think of the 2D array as one dimensional array and then derive the appropriate row, offset pairs for indices.

```
import java.util.Arrays;    

public class Bubble2DSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Started");

        int[][] matrix = {{49,44,54,55,100,344}, {1,1,2,6,12,32}};

        sortMatrix(matrix);

        System.out.println("Printing output ");

        for(int[] rowArr : matrix) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rowArr));
        }
    }

    private static void sortMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
        int row = matrix.length;
        int col = matrix[0].length;
        int totalCount = row * col;

        System.out.println("totalCount : " +totalCount);

        boolean noSwaps = false;
        for(int i = 0; !noSwaps; i++) {
            noSwaps = true;

            for(int j = 1; j < totalCount - i; j++) {
                int currentRow = (j-1) / col;
                int currentOffset = (j-1) % col;
                int nextRow = j / col;
                int nextOffset = j % col;

                if( matrix[currentRow][currentOffset] > matrix[nextRow][nextOffset]) {
                    //swapping
                    int temp = matrix[nextRow][nextOffset];
                    matrix[nextRow][nextOffset] = matrix[currentRow][currentOffset];
                    matrix[currentRow][currentOffset] = temp;

                    noSwaps = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Started
totalCount : 12
Printing output 
[1, 1, 2, 6, 12, 32]
[44, 49, 54, 55, 100, 344]
```